# What is the name of the category of viruses that affect only one side of the body?

Tags: human-biology, cell-biology, immunology, virus, virology

The [Varicella zoster virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varicella_zoster_virus) causes chickenpox in children and [shingles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingles) in adults.

When the virus attacks as **shingles**, one of its distinguishing characteristics is that it [only affects one side of the body](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingles#Signs_and_symptoms). (As shown in the link and verbally identified by a doctor I spoke to). This happens because the nerve cells themselves are infected - and are partitioned on different sides of the body.

> At first the rash appears similar to the first appearance of hives;
> however, unlike hives, shingles causes skin changes limited to a
> dermatome, normally resulting in a stripe or belt-like pattern that is
> limited to one side of the body and does not cross the midline.[13]
> Zoster sine herpete ("zoster without herpes") describes a person who
> has all of the symptoms of shingles except this characteristic
> rash.[16]
>
> <sup>*From Wikipedia*</sup>

My question is: What is the name of the category of viruses that affect only one side of the body?

Comment: I don't think there is a name for the "category", or that it really is a category unto itself.

Comment: "unilateral" would make for a convenient shorthand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** Viruses that affect only one side of the body are not categorized by this information.

**Long Answer:** For people who likes details

Several types of [virus classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virus_classification) exists:

- Baltimore: Classified by the type of DNA or RNA that is carried by the virus
- Holmes: Classified by the target organisms of the viruses (plants, bacteria, animals)
- LHT: Classified using several physical differences (More specific and complex)

For example, Shingles would be classified as:

Baltimore: Group I (double DNA stranded viruses)

Holmes: Group III Zoophaginae (animals)

**LHT:**

- Order: *Herpesvirales*
- Family: *Herpesviridae*
- Subfamily: *Alphaherpesvirinae*
- Genus: *Varicellovirus*
- Specie: *Human herpesvirus 3 (HHV-3)*